# How can I echo and redirect in this Jquery code?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am trying to echo the url generated in the code below and set it as a redirect after the AJAX submit occurs.

I can get a redirect working but struggling with figuring out how to call the "ShareUrl" to actually use the url being created in this section of the code below that creates it as a text link above.

window.location ="shareUrl" is the part I cant get right...

```
jQuery('.fpd-share-process').addClass('fpd-hidden');
jQuery('.fpd-share-url').attr('href', shareUrl).text(shareUrl).removeClass('fpd-hidden');
 window.location = "shareUrl";
```

Does anyone have any advice or a solution to get this working?

```
<script type="text/javascript">

jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    jQuery('#fpd-share-button').click(function(evt) {

        evt.preventDefault();

        jQuery(".fpd-share-widget, .fpd-share-url").addClass('fpd-hidden');
        jQuery('.fpd-share-process').removeClass('fpd-hidden');

        var variationsSer = $productWrapper.find('.variations_form .variations select')
                            .filter(function(index, element) {
                                return $(element).val() != "";
                            }).serialize();

        var scale = $selector.width() > 800 ? Number(800 / $selector.width()).toFixed(2) : 1;
        fancyProductDesigner.getViewsDataURL(function(dataURLs) {

            var dataURL = dataURLs[0],
                data = {
                action: 'fpd_createshareurl',
                image: dataURL,
                product: JSON.stringify(fancyProductDesigner.getProduct()),
            };

            jQuery.post("<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>", data, function(response) {

                if(response.share_id !== undefined) {

                    var pattern = new RegExp('(share_id=).*?(&|$)'),
                        shareUrl = window.location.href + '?' + variationsSer;

                    if(shareUrl.search(pattern) >= 0){
                        shareUrl = shareUrl.replace(pattern,'$1' + response.share_id + '$2');
                    }
                    else{
                        shareUrl = shareUrl + (shareUrl.indexOf('?')>0 ? '&' : '?') + 'share_id=' + response.share_id;
                    }

                    jsSocials.setDefaults('facebook', {
                        logo: ' fpd-icon-share-facebook'
                    });

                    jsSocials.setDefaults('twitter', {
                        logo: ' fpd-icon-share-twitter'
                    });

                    jsSocials.setDefaults('googleplus', {
                        logo: '  fpd-icon-share-google-plus'
                    });

                    jsSocials.setDefaults('linkedin', {
                        logo: ' fpd-icon-share-linkedin'
                    });

                    jsSocials.setDefaults('pinterest', {
                        logo: ' fpd-icon-share-pinterest'
                    });

                    jsSocials.setDefaults('email', {
                        logo: ' fpd-icon-share-mail'
                    });

                    <?php $shares = fpd_get_option('fpd_sharing_social_networks'); ?>                                   jQuery(".fpd-share-widget").empty().jsSocials({
                        url: shareUrl,
                        shares: <?php echo is_array($shares) ? json_encode($shares) : '['.$shares.']'; ?> ,
                        showLabel: false,
                        text: "<?php echo FPD_Settings_Labels::get_translation( 'misc', 'share:_default_text' ); ?>"
                    }).removeClass('fpd-hidden');
                }

                jQuery('.fpd-share-process').addClass('fpd-hidden');
                jQuery('.fpd-share-url').attr('href', shareUrl).text(shareUrl).removeClass('fpd-hidden');
                window.location = "shareUrl";
            }, 'json');

        }, 'transparent', {multiplier: scale, format: 'png'});

    });

});
</script>
```

Comment: What's the point of making changes to the DOM right before you assign to `window.location`? That's going to reload the page, so anything you do to the current page is discarded.

Comment: Don't put `shareUrl` in quotes.

Comment: That is fine. The script saves the users image they created and then displays a share url. What I want is for the user to be redirected right to the share url so they can see the final image rather than just seeing the link. The "shareUrl" that is being created is what I am trying to set as the redirect.

Comment: Then what's the problem? `window.location = shareUrl;`

Comment: No quotes did the trick!! Thanks so much!!!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the value in the variable, don't quote it, since that makes it a literal string. Write:

```
window.location = shareUrl;
```